# Exception on NMSConnectionFactory in Native API Sample Code

Tags: c#, .net, sabre

I'm getting an exception in the StartSession method of the Native API sample code, NativeAppWin, in C#.  If I'm reading the error correctly it looks like the NMS library does not provide an implementation for CreateConnectionAsync?

Does anyone have any ideas?
What is the version of Apache/NMS in Nuget that we should be using?
I'm using the following.

Apache.NMS 2.0

Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ  1.8

[image]

Here's the exception details:

```
Apache.NMS.NMSConnectionException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Could not create the IConnectionFactory implementation: Method 'CreateConnectionAsync' in type 'Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory' from assembly 'Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=82756feee3957618' does not have an implementation.
  Source=Apache.NMS
  StackTrace:
   at Apache.NMS.NMSConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionFactory(Uri uriProvider, Object[] constructorParams)
   at Apache.NMS.NMSConnectionFactory..ctor(Uri uriProvider, Object[] constructorParams)
   at NativeAppWin.Form1.StartSession() in C:\Projects\Testers\NativeAPI-DotNet-Demo\NativeAppWin\Form1.cs:line 67
   at NativeAppWin.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\Testers\NativeAPI-DotNet-Demo\NativeAppWin\Form1.cs:line 141
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
TypeLoadException: Method 'CreateConnectionAsync' in type 'Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory' from assembly 'Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=82756feee3957618' does not have an implementation.
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the version in Nuget for Apache.NMS to 1.8 (to match version of Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ) and it no longer throws the exception.  I don't see anything in the Native API documentation that states what versions to use, so I installed the latest on both.  Hindsight, not a great idea... and maybe I should have kept the versions the same when given the chance.

It sounds like there are some significant changes in v2.0 so, for Sabre Native API purposes I would try the older v1.8.